# How to call event calendar without viewing the calendar?

Tags: android, events, android-intent, android-calendar

I am creating an schedule with a timetable. My question is, when i need to create a new event i call the activity by this code.

```
   public void callEventDialog(int line, int column){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(startWeek.getTimeInMillis() + column * DIM + line * 30 * 60 * 1000);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "title");
    intent.putExtra(Events.DTSTART, c.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, c.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, c.getTimeInMillis() + 1800 * 1000);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}
```

But when i click on ok button i don't want to view the calendar activity. I only need the registration of event not the calendar and get out. How i can do this???
Thanks for your time and help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add event directly to the calendar, you need to use content resolver and request calendar permissions - no calendar activity is used.

Permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Putting event into database example:

```
public static int insertEventToDb(Context context, Event event, int calendarId) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, event.getName());
    values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, event.getLocation());
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, event.getStartDate().getTime());
    values.put(Events.DTEND, event.getEndDate().getTime());
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, event.getDescription());
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1").getID());

    Uri result = context.getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    int eventId = Integer.valueOf(result.getPathSegments().get(1));
    return eventId;
}
```

You also need ID of the calendar which you want to insert data to. You can get that by using SQLite query to find it out or by creating your own calendar (that should by done only via `SyncAdapter`). This is another example, you will probably need to modify it by your needs (`Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE` is my custom):

```
Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "LOCAL")
                .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE).build();
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {Calendars._ID}, null, null, null);
```

You can find further information on [Android Developers site - Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).